# Blank screen on Z620 after install of 16.04.02 server

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, system-installation, uefi

I can't get a Basic server install to work (only installing Utilities, SSL and Basic Server), where I get the Ubuntu purple boot screen, and then the screen goes blank (backlit with no text).

The BIOS is set with Fast boot and secure boot disabled, the Storage ROMs option is set to Legacy (not EFI, though I tried that too with no results.

I also tried, in GRUB, to change the boot setting to "nomodeset" with no results either. This was suggested if the video card isn't recognized, to get it to work once, and then update the video drivers.

I have also tried the recovery mode option, and exit out to root.  This was another way to possibly update video drivers, starting with "sudo apt-get update", but I'm getting a various errors that the drive seems to be read-only.

The Z620 has BIOS 3.91 (I have another Z620 with a BIOS version 3.87 with same results) dual XEONs E5-2690s, 64 GB RAM and I have tried 3 different brands of SSDs.

This is a single boot installation. I have in Grub tried both the UEFI forced, and non forced options during installation.

Any assistance on what to look for would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have had same problem but I found an answer elsewhere, as the server IS running, I can open a console with PuTTY from a windowes machine. The answer I was given was hit Ctrl-ALT-F1 to get a TTY1 screen on the server itself. Don't know why the login screen doesnt come up. But at least you can control it.

Comment: Could you insert where you found your answer? You can follow these guidelines: https://askubuntu.com/help/referencing